# Review a paper with recent coauthors

Tags: publications, peer-review, conflict-of-interest

I got a request to review a paper from a journal. I know the topic area well, but I've had some recent collaborations with some of the authors. Should I decline the request because of this? What is the common practice here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's potentially a conflict of interest, but some fields are small and have few competent reviewers. Tell the editors, and let them decide. They can offset a bias in their final decision in an informed way, or take you off the review if they believe this poses a problem.

Comment: There are separate links to accept or reject the request, so I'm not sure if this is a possibility.

Comment: @user11550 Presumably you know the name of the editor though, so can make direct contact with them?

Comment: Isn't there an email through which it was sent? A "reply" usually works.

Comment: When you submit the review, you may be able to write "confidential comments to the editor", which the authors don't see. You can mention recent collaborations there. Of course, that presupposes that you have already written the review...

Comment: Given that any time that the editor spends waiting to find out that they can't use the review is time they've not used for finding a new reviewer, it would always be best to clarify this with the editor as soon as possible. Hopefully this should be obvious, but I wouldn't want any reader misunderstanding @StephanKolassa's comment as a suggestion to write the review and then notify the editor of the potential conflict of interest.

Comment: @Ian_Fin: I was thinking more along the lines of writing the review, since the OP presumably *is* an expert on the topic, but then informing the editor of anything that could motivate him to take the review with a tiny grain of salt.

Comment: From personal experience, I would suggest directly e-mailing the editor who was named in the request to review, or the editor-in-chief if there wasn't one.  The "reply" may go to an editorial assistant who doesn't know what to do with your question.  (If you can't get a reply from them about this question, I might suggest these are not editors you want to review for (or submit papers to!))